# How can I combine Application.route() and subrouters in Express?

Tags: express

I would like to have a route with the fixed context prefix of my application and then attach Subresources to it as `express.Router`s.

From http://expressjs.com/api.html#router.route:

> Returns an instance of a single route which you can then use to handle
>   HTTP verbs with optional middleware. Use router.route() to avoid
>   duplicate route naming and thus typo errors.

The following does not work because `use` is undefined for the return value of `app.route()`:

```
var app = express();
var user = express.Router();
// ...
app.route(config.context).use('/user', user);
```

This does work:

```
var app = express();
var user = express.Router();
// ...
app.route(config.context + '/user').all(user);
```

Is there a way of combining route() and use() in such a way that I won't have to prepend `config.context` to all my subresource paths?

Where can I find the API docs for the object that is returned from `express().route()`?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, so rubber duck debugging did it again. This is what I ended up doing:

```
var app = express();
var api = express.Router();
app.use(config.context, api);
api.use('/user', user);
```

Makes `express().route()` seem somewhat pointless though.